# On the definition/convergence of dirihclet series

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I have 2 questions"

1. It's often said the appropriate sum converges as long as $s$ has real part more than $1$. Are we deciding on the branch of $k=0$ here: 
   $n^s=e^{(ln(n)+2\pi ik)s}$? If not, why does the sum converge?
2. Why is the dirichlet series analytic inside of where it converges (again I'm assuming we fix $k=0$?

Comment: (1) Yes, we take k=0. That is, we take the branch of the logarithm for which $n^{-s}$ is real for real $s$. For (2), something like Morera's theorem from complex analysis is very helpful.